# Two divs with no particular height. How to vertically fill second div?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with data that comes from an API call so I can't set a fixed height because the content is dynamic but I want to have the second div start at the bottom of the first and fill the page. I tried using flexbox because compatibility says it should work with IE but it doesn't look like it does. Here's simplistic code of the closest I can get so far.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="div1">dynamic content</div>
    <div class="div2">fill the rest of the page</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.div1 {
    height: auto; /* I can't set a specific height because it depends on the content */
}
.div2 {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

It looks good in Chrome and Firefox but the problem with this is that when I resize the browser in IE div1's content overflows the div so div2's content is covered by the overflow. Is there any way to force div1's content to stay inside the div in IE so it acts like it does in Chrome and Firefox?

Comment: Is the dynamic content text only or is it HTML?

Comment: It's select2 multi that gets its options from an API call so it could be an empty box or it could have really long options forcing it to be 3 "lines" tall.

Answer (score 0):

You need to see the height on the parent of the .container - this will be html,body

```
html,
body {
   height: 100%;
}
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/fvxz793t/)

Comment: It looks like I forgot to say that the parent has a defined height but it works well with Chrome and Firefox. My problem is specifically why the code I have posted acts differently in IE.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is for the child `div` to inherit the height of its parent.

So in this case, the `.container` should inherit its height from the `html` and `body`. 
Also you want `div2` to inherit from its parent i.e. `.container`.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: inherit;
}

.div1 {
  height: auto;
  background-color: aqua;
  text-overflow: auto;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: green;
  height: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
  <div class="div2">fill the rest of the page</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like I forgot to say that the parent has a defined height but it works well with Chrome and Firefox. My problem is specifically why the code I have and you posted acts differently in IE.